# Remove and then adding runtime event listener again in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

what i am trying to achieve here is... if i touch one image it gets disabled. then i want to enable it by touching another image. but after disabling i can't re-enable it.
i have a touch event for first image which i call using

```
Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", diceFunction2 )
```

and i remove it using

```
Runtime:removeEventListener( "touch", diceFunction2 )
```

but i am trying to add it again using this touch event handler

```
local function guti11touched( event )
  if event.phase == "began" then
     if playerTurn%2==0 then
        if rand == 6 and gutiStatus.guti11.status == false then
            gutiStatus.guti11.status = true
            gutiStatus.guti11.count = 1
            local i = gutiStatus.guti11.count
            transition.moveTo(guti11, {x=background.x+player1Sequence[i][1],y=background.y-player1Sequence[i][2]})
        elseif gutiStatus.guti11.status == true and gutiStatus.guti11.count+rand <= 57 then
            gutiStatus.guti11.count = gutiStatus.guti11.count + rand
            local i = gutiStatus.guti11.count
            transition.moveTo(guti11, {x=background.x+player1Sequence[i][1],y=background.y-player1Sequence[i][2]})
            if i == 57 then
                guti11.isClickable = false
            end
        end
     end
  elseif event.phase == "ended" then
    Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", diceFunction2 ) 
  end
return true
end
```

can someone please tell me what is the correct way to do it and what i'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

this is my first image eventhandler. i already tried by adding dice:addEventListener( "touch", diceFunction2 ) , but in that case the image just keep rotating and never stop, and as i'm choosing images randomly so can i do it in place of runtime?

```
--for rotating dice
local function diceFunction2( event )

if event.phase == "began" then
      local laserChannel = audio.play( laserSound )
      rand=math.random(6)
      dice = display.newImage("images/dice3droll.png")
      dice.x = 75
      dice.y = 480
      dice:scale(1/scale_factor,1/scale_factor)
      display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( dice )
      dice.isFocus = true
      Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", rotateDice )
   elseif dice.isFocus then              
       if event.phase == "moved" then
         elseif event.phase == "ended" then
            if rand == 1 then
                Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", rotateDice)
                dice:removeSelf()
                local dice1 = display.newImage("images/ek.png")
                dice1.x = 75
                dice1.y = 480
                dice1:addEventListener( "touch", diceFunction2 ) 
                display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
                dice.isFocus = false


            elseif rand == 2 then
                Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", rotateDice)
                dice:removeSelf()
                local dice2 = display.newImage("images/dui.png")
                dice2.x = 75
                dice2.y = 480
                display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
                dice.isFocus = false    


            elseif rand == 3 then
                Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", rotateDice)
                dice:removeSelf()
                local dice3 = display.newImage("images/tin.png")
                dice3.x = 75
                dice3.y = 480
                display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
                dice.isFocus = false    

            elseif rand == 4 then
                Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", rotateDice)
                dice:removeSelf()
                local dice4 = display.newImage("images/charr.png")
                dice4.x = 75
                dice4.y = 480
                display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
                dice.isFocus = false


            elseif rand == 5 then
                Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", rotateDice)
                dice:removeSelf()
                local dice5 = display.newImage("images/pach.png")
                dice5.x = 75
                dice5.y = 480
                display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
                dice.isFocus = false    


            elseif rand == 6 then
                Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", rotateDice)
                dice:removeSelf()
                local dice6 = display.newImage("images/chokka.png")
                dice6.x = 75
                dice6.y = 480
                display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
                dice.isFocus = false        
            end

       end
end 
end
```

this is my rotatedice function

```
local function rotateDice()
  dice.rotation = dice.rotation + 200
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime touch handlers cover the whole screen.  If you want a touch event on an object, you normally add the touch event directly to that object:

someImage:addEventListener("touch", myTouchFunction)

Then I would not worry about adding and removing the listeners but instead set some flags that would indicate if the touch was allowed to happen or not.

Comment: in my case i am not working with particular image, when i click one image it randomly changes to another image. so i am not sure if I can use someImage:addEventListener("touch", myTouchFunction)

Comment: i have updated my question with the functions, please have a look

Comment: i added the touch event to the object and set flag, but i had to modify my code a lot, but at last it worked. thanks for your advice

Comment: I would recommend using sprites for this.  You would have one display object that has 6 frames, one for each face of the dice.  Then you just change which frame shows.

Comment: OK thanks again... I will try to do this using sprites too...thanks for this advice..will let you know if I succeed. :D